# Can the same public address used for Ether be used to receive other coins as well?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, erc20, ether

I am planning for a cryptocurrency app, and am trying to figure out something I haven't been able to find an answer to.

On the Etherum blockchain, a user has a public address used for receiving coins, and a private key used to send. There are also many other coins based on the Etherum blockchain; most ICOs seem to be using the ERC20 protocol to issue their coins.

Can a regular Ethereum public address be used for receiving all kinds of such coins, or only for Ether?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Under the hood, token balances is usually just a `mapping` state variable inside the ERC20 token contract. The `mapping` holds an Ethereum address as the key and the balance as the value. The address can be either a basic [Externally Owned Account (EOA)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5828/what-is-an-eoa-account) address or the address of a smart contract (ie, a wallet), and the same address can be in multiple ERC20 contracts.

Here is a simple example of an address on Rinkeby that has both Ether and tokens (ATT)

[image]

The decision of where to store your tokens depends on your security preferences. If you use an EOA account then there is a risk of someone getting a hold of your private key and transferring funds/tokens out. For this reason, some people prefer to either use a wallet, or store their assets across multiple EOA accounts.